# Fastest Java HTTP Library

Tags: java, networking, http

I’m working on a program that sends A LOT of HTTP requests (in an ordered way, since they depend on each other) and checks their response. I’d like to know what’s the most high-throughput oriented library for this.

Answer (score 1):

The new [HTTP client in Java 11](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/package-summary.html) is pretty good. I use it for site crawling. Works great.

Supports HTTP/2 and WebSocket for fast connections.

And supports asynchronous tasks.